# pip installed scripts in ~/.local/bin with outdated shebangs

Tags: python, pip

A while ago I installed several packages using `pip` with the `--user` option, with the result that I have several scripts in `~/.local/bin` which have the hardcoded shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.3
```

However, in the meanwhile, my Python distribution has been upgraded to Python 3.4, with the result that these scripts don't work anymore.

**How do I upgrade these scripts to point to the new Python version?**

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the package in question, but this script never seems to get removed. Likewise, `pip install --upgrade` does not touch the scripts.

Comment: are you sure that you are using the right (version 3.4) pip? check the output of `which pip`

Comment: @Salo: pip points to `python-exec2`, which seems to do the right thing. Also, when I install packages, it correctly installs the 3.4 versions. Only these scripts don't seem to get updated.

Comment: mmh ok, did you try `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall`?